# Семантически верный код ошибки при отсутствии данных по неполному URI?

Tags: http, uri

```
example.com/dir/1.html  - 200
example.com/dir/        - ?
example.com/di          - 404
```

Comment: index выводите, раз это у вас папка ;)

Comment: @Visman Нет, условие таково что данные отсутствуют. Но вообще вашу т.з. разделяет Лебедев если мне не изменяет память.